# ASP.NET MVC on IIS - URL/routing to start page after publish not correct

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC page. Debugging on my development machine with IIS Express works just fine, start page is `localhost:xxxx/Home/Index`.

After publishing on "real" IIS (different machine, version 8.5), the start page does not have the correct URL. The page of `Home/Index` is displayed but shows simply as `http://[servername]:[port]`. Route `/Home/Index` does not seem to be applied.

Problem: the page is using AJAX for an autocomplete field. Of course the action is then "not found", because in the AJAX call, the URL is wrong (controller name missing).

I put an action link on top that results in `/Home/Index`. I click it, `/Home/Index` is properly used and displayed, autocomplete works as expected.

Is this some mistake I made in IIS config or in my ASP.NET MVC application?

My `RouteConfig`:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Index",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

`Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: @Jackdaw : I would post more if I understood the problem. I get no error navigating the site or opening the start page. It is just that the initial / default route does not seem to be used as URL. The controller is straight-forward, simply "return View()", no custom routes. Therefore "All parts related to the problem" is not something I can do since I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: The exact opposite: If I enter `http://[servername]:[port]`  I want it to automatically display `http://[servername]:[port]/Home/Index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything else failed, I decided: why not do it in a simple way.
Did this now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if (window.location.href.indexOf("Home")==-1){
    window.location.href = window.location.href+"Home/Index";
    }
...
```

All other suggested attempts had no effect.

Comment: Since the commenter deleted his comments, these were the suggestions: swap the routing, clear browser cache, restart website, adjust startup options in project properties.